# Rails ActiveModel inaccessible values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When i written my poll app i was get an error:
http://screenshot.sh/m3eeke1da49kL

So I tried to comment code and inspected value.
http://screenshot.sh/mGR8cOuGizBRx

Why i can't access the values? There is a code of helper method:

```
 def poll_option(poll)
    @option = VoteOption.find_by(poll_id: poll.id)
    content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do
        content_tag(:label) do
          unless current_user.voted_for?(poll)
           radio_button_tag 'vote_option[id]', @option.id
          end
         @option.title
        end
        visualize_votes_for @option
    end
    @option.inspect
  end
```

Comment: you should use the `bybug` or `pry` to debug this problem seems you are missing something here.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to be the same that's throwing the error. Anyway, it's likely been caused by you looping through an array and there happens to be a nil/empty element in it.

Comment: ok i resolved the problem but the code

Answer (score 1):

ok i resolved the problem but the code

 `def poll_option(poll)
    @option = VoteOption.find_by(poll_id: poll.id)
    @option.each do |o|
      content_tag :div, class: 'form-group' do
        content_tag(:label) do
          unless current_user.voted_for?(poll)
           radio_button_tag 'vote_option[id]', o.id
          end
         o.title
        end
        visualize_votes_for o
        end
    end`

end

Gives an error that "each" is undefined method.